# QScrollArea - how to enable touch interactions to scroll to next item?

Tags: qt, symbian

I'm using the Nokia Qt SDK and designed a small banner carousel in the top area. It looks like this:

[image: UI demo]

The hierarchy looks like:

[image: UI hierarchy]

After installing this in the emulator, I try to make it scrollable (flinging). It's a simple task I would guess (like `ScrollView` in Android, or `UIScrollView` in iOS), but so far no joy. All links in the internet point me of custom scroll implementations etc etc. which I don't want to do nor expect to do as Qt should be a higher level framework? What is the state of the art here? ;-)

Question in short: How can I make this `QScrollArea` respond to touch (fling, scroll, drag etc) events and reveal the other widgets in the queue? I'm not expecting it to be able to "snap" into a child widget (which is another requirement later ;)).

Comment: I found QFingerScrollArea now: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPQ1VlyMPYU

Comment: QScrollArea supports touch interactions directly   (at least in newer qts). Although I have not figured out, in which cases (there are two controls based on QAbstractScrollArea in my project. One controls scrolls on touch, the other does not). Would be nice, if the answer gets updated

Comment: `QScroller::grabGesture(scrollArea->viewport(), QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);` worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Flickable (at http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/07/19/kinetic-scrolling-on-any-widgets/) and FlickCharm (linked to from that first address ) either to have an idea on how to implement it on your own or use it as is.

Note that it might not be necessary if your target is Maemo, as its Qt port handles it.

Comment: I think this is the new link: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/07/19/kinetic-scrolling-on-any-widgets/

Comment: @frozenkoi Why not edit the question to add the correct link?

Comment: Could you please [edit] to add an example of how to use that? Please don't post link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling gestures?  I haven't used the gesture support yet, but it looks like it's as easy as

```
scrollEvents->grabGesture(Qt::SwipeGesture);
// or...
scrollEvents->grabGesture(Qt::PanGesture);
```

I don't know if QScrollArea already handles gestures, so if that doesn't work, you may need to sub-class QScrollArea and override the `event` method to handle gesture events, as described in the [Gestures Programming Guide](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/gestures-overview.html).

Comment: Is this for Qt 4.7 ? I have to use Qt 4.6 due to the Nokia Qt SDK download, correct? At least no option to download 4.7. (SDK installer is broken, website download only offers bundled 4.6).

Comment: OK, I see it;s also available in 4.6 documentation, will give it a try, thx!

Comment: Yup, tried - and no joy. The whole story seems to be complicated. As some people implemented custom Touch/Fling etc responders, I'm quite shocked. Was hoping to find some more finished solutions.